# Missing CORS on the response header

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

Basically I'd like to know if it's up to the company (https://documenu.com/) to "fix" one of their endpoints or if it has something to do with my code.

I tried almost all of the other endpoints (https://documenu.com/docs) with the same code below and all of them worked fine except the one being discussed here.

The error message I get is:

> Ensure CORS response header values are valid
>
> A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request was blocked because of
> invalid or missing response headers of the request or the associated
> preflight request.
>
> To fix this issue, ensure the response to the CORS request and/or the
> associated preflight request are not missing headers and use valid
> header values.
>
> Note that if an opaque response is sufficient, the request's mode can
> be set to no-cors to fetch the resource with CORS disabled; that way
> CORS headers are not required but the response content is inaccessible
> (opaque).

I've tried using through Node,Live-reload but nothing.

I read about CORS and from what I understood, it would be up to the company to add CORS to their responses' headers.

What do you think?

```
const api = apiKey;
const myHeaders = new Headers();

myHeaders.append('x-api-key', api);

const requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow',
  mode: 'cors',
};
const endpoint = 'https://api.documenu.com/v2/menuitems/search/geo?lat=40.688072&lon=-73.997385&distance=1&search=buffalo%20chicken';

fetch(`${endpoint}`, requestOptions)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) -> [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) - HTTP | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS): _"Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header based mechanism that **allows a server to indicate** any origins (domain, scheme, or port) other than its own from which a browser should permit loading resources."_

Comment: Yes. CORS is something that needs to be put in on the server-side

Comment: @DanielW. Question: _"Basically I'd like to know if it's up to the company to "fix" one of their endpoints"_ - Answer: _"CORS allows a server..."_ (explained in any document about CORS)

Comment: @Andreas Because there are other mechanics, like used within wikipedia for example that require additional URL parameters for CORS to work (it actually depends on implementation). So as a consumer of an endpoint by a company like that, its totally understandable to raise a doubt on both sides if something doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @DanielW. Then that would be a "read the manual" question which should be closed.

Comment: There is nothing about that in the manual if you read it, you'd know that. Props to the ppl who vote before reading.

Comment: The domain is not active anymore, their whole service seems to be down.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you are right, the company is the one to fix the issue, because they are opposed to sending the CORS header.

Using the API preview on their website, you are also right about all of the endpoints working but the one you mention.

Edit:

I have removed the link to the documentation because the domain is not active anymore.